# Why doesn't React re-render when list in state is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm develepoing a chat page with a React class component. The code should append every message that I sent by the input to `<MessageGroup sentByUser>` block

```
class ChatPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userMessages: [[0, 'First example message'], [1, 'Second msg']],
            userMessageNextId: 2,
        };
        this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.userMessages);
        return (
            <div className="chat-page mb-5">
                <div className="messages-container">
                    <MessageGroup sentBy="Juan">
                        <Message>This is first message</Message>
                        <Message>This is second message</Message>
                    </MessageGroup>
                    <MessageGroup sentByUser>
                        {this.state.userMessages.map((val) => (<Message key={val[0]}>{val[1]}</Message>))}
                    </MessageGroup>
                </div>
                <div className="input-container">
                    <div className="input-group">
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="message-text" placeholder="Type something..."/>
                        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.sendMessage}>Send</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    sendMessage() {
        const messageText = document.querySelector("#message-text").value;
        if (!messageText?.trim()) return;
        this.setState(state => {
            console.log('Setting state...')
            const newArray = [...state.userMessages, [state.userMessageNextId, messageText]];
            return {
                userMessages: newArray,
                userMessageNextId: state.userMessageNextId + 1
            }
        })
    }
}
```

When I'm debugging my code, I see two default messages from the state. And when I send a message, I see "Setting state..." and new needed array in the console, but the UI is not changed. What's wrong here?

Comment: Maybe try to write `[...state.userMessages, [state.userMessageNextId, messageText]]` directly instead of creating the `newArray`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but It's not the problem. The array updates well. The `console.log` on the first line of `render` shows new array with new added elements well. But I can't see them on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You should use controlled components in React to manage the input value instead of `document.querySelector`.

```js
class ChatPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userMessages: [[0, 'First example message'], [1, 'Second msg']],
            userMessageNextId: 2,
            messageText: '' // Add messageText to the state
        };
        this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this);
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.userMessages);
        return (
            <div className="chat-page mb-5">
                <div className="messages-container">
                    <MessageGroup sentBy="Juan">
                        <Message>This is the first message</Message>
                        <Message>This is the second message</Message>
                    </MessageGroup>
                    <MessageGroup sentByUser>
                        {this.state.userMessages.map((val) => (
                            <Message key={val[0]}>{val[1]}</Message>
                        ))}
                    </MessageGroup>
                </div>
                <div className="input-container">
                    <div className="input-group">
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            id="message-text"
                            placeholder="Type something..."
                            value={this.state.messageText} // Bind the input value to state
                            onChange={this.handleInputChange} // Add onChange event handler
                        />
                        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.sendMessage}>
                            Send
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    sendMessage() {
        if (!this.state.messageText.trim()) return;
        this.setState((state) => {
            console.log('Setting state...');
            const newArray = [...state.userMessages, [state.userMessageNextId, state.messageText]];
            return {
                userMessages: newArray,
                userMessageNextId: state.userMessageNextId + 1,
                messageText: '' // Clear the input field after sending the message
            };
        });
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {
        this.setState({ messageText: event.target.value }); // Update the messageText state with the input value
    }
}

export default ChatPage;
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for the useful advice. But the re-render problem is still actual.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is your use of a native DOM method to interrogate the DOM to grab the input value when really you should be keeping that value in state, and using a method to update that value whenever the input `onChange` event is fired. Then, when the button is clicked, you can then copy that `input` state value into the `userMessages` state.

(Using `value={this.state.input}` makes the input a controlled input - changes in state are reflected back to its value when the component re-renders. It makes sure everything is sync'd, and is a more "React way" of approaching the problem.)

Further: you'll probably find an array of objects a little more easy to work with. Property names are far more meaningful than index values. For example you can set an `id` property which can serve is both the unique object identifier, and the `key` for the iterated messages.

Obviously it's ultimately your choice but I decided to use them in this example to show them working.

```js
const { Component } = React;

class ChatPage extends Component {
    
  // Setting up the initial `userMessages` as an array of objects,
  // and an initial state for `input`
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userMessages: [
        { id: '1', msg: 'First example message' },
        { id: '2', msg: 'Second msg' }
      ],
      input: ''
    };
    this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this);
    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
  }

  // When the input value is changed update its state
  handleInput(e) {
    this.setState({ input: e.target.value });
  }

  // When the button is clicked spread out the previous
  // state, and set `userMessages` to be the old `userMessages`
  // state with a new object added to it. The new object uses
  // the length of the current `userMessages` array to set the id,
  // and then sets its msg property to the value of the input state
  // Finally the input state is reset
  sendMessage(e) {
    this.setState(prev => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        userMessages: [
          ...prev.userMessages,
          {
            id: prev.userMessages.length + 1,
            msg: this.state.input
          }
        ]
      }
    });
    this.setState({ input: '' });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="chat-page mb-5">
        <div className="messages-container">
          <MessageGroup sentBy="Juan">
            <Message>This is first message</Message>
            <Message>This is second message</Message>
          </MessageGroup>
          <MessageGroup sentByUser>
            {this.state.userMessages.map(obj => {
              return <Message key={obj.id}>{obj.msg}</Message>;
            })}
          </MessageGroup>
        </div>
        <div className="input-container">
          <div className="input-group">
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              id="message-text"
              value={this.state.input}
              placeholder="Type something..."
              onChange={this.handleInput}
             />
            <button
              className="btn btn-primary"
              onClick={this.sendMessage}
            >Send
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}


function Message({ children }) {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}

function MessageGroup({ children }) {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}

const node = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(node);
root.render(<ChatPage />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```